# cannot mongodb console in OSX using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i am able to run mongodb in my apple console, and `vim` the `mongo.log` 
right now, i just want to open up the mongodb console so that i can test queries in the console just like the examples in http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tutorial

at the moment, the cursor is not returned:

```
> mongodb
all output going to :/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

and the cursor is not returned. i was expecting the cursor to be returned to so i can do the following :

```
 > mongodb
 all output going to :/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
 > test = {name : "bouncingHippo"}
 > db.family.save(test)
 > "ok"
```

What am i doing wrong? i am using mongoose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear which console you are getting this output from, as the Node console won't return anything usable if you just enter `mongodb`.

If what you are trying to do is just launch a MongoDB console, you will need to first launch the `mongod` process and then attach to that process with the MongoDB console.  The MongoDB console is called `mongo`.  In the simplest test, you can launch `mongod` from one terminal window and then `mongo` from another.  In the terminal window that is running `mongo` you can then work through the examples in the [tutorial](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tutorial).  Your pseudo code would then look like:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.1
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:18070/test
> test = {name : "bouncingHippo"}
{ "name" : "bouncingHippo" }
> db.family.save(test)
```

If you are trying to use Mongoose for the pseudo code you have in your question, it would be more like the following from the Node console (assuming Node.js and Mongoose are installed)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/test');
var testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
})
var Test = db.model('Test', testSchema)
var test = new Test({ name: 'bouncinghippo' })
test.save()
```

Comment: this answer is very detailed, and very helpful for newcomers. upvote!

Comment: @Andre how do i launch the Node console then?

Comment: You can launch the Node interactive shell (console) by typing `node` in your terminal window.  That should give you a `>` prompt.